# Помогите Пожалуйста c js

Tags: javascript

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Редактор разметки текстов

Чтобы упростить жизнь контент-менеджеру сайта, сделали простую CMS, в которой тексты статей набираются в кастомной разметке.

Набор операторов ограничен:

- Заголовки
- Неупорядоченные списки одного уровня вложенности
- Абзацы — Ссылки

Необходимо написать тело преобразующей функции

```
module.exports = (str) => {
    //  Ваш код здесь
};
```

Формат ввода

```
= head

text ((https://ya.ru link)) text.

* item
* item
```

Формат вывода

```
<h1>head</h1><p>text <a href="https://ya.ru">link</a> text.</p><ul><li>item</li><li>item</li></ul>
```

Примечания

Незначимые пробелы и переносы строк на выходе не имеют значения, т.к. в тестах html приводится к одной строке, а лишние пробелы удаляются;

Одинарные кавычки в тесте приводятся к двойным;

Формат заголовка (Начало строки, знак равно, пробел, текст заголовка, конец строки);

Формат абзаца (Начало строки, текст абзаца, конец строки);

Формат списка (Пункт списка, повторенный один и более раз: Начало строки, звёздочка, пробел, текст, конец строки. До и после списка пустые строки);

Формат ссылки (Две открывающие скобки, адрес ссылки, первый пробел, текст ссылки с любым кол-вом пробелов, две закрывающие скобки)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: лучше бы просто взяли markdown. или wysiwyg поставили

Comment: как это сделать ?

Comment: так это не рабочая проблема, а домашнее задание? решайте сплитом по переносу строки, анализом первого символа и регулярками

Comment: я не знаю как вообще писать (( подскажите пожалуйста правильный код

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Один из вариантов:

```js
module.exports = (str) => {
  let html = '';

  let context = null;

  const linkRegExp = /\(\((?<href>.+?) (?<text>.+?)\)\)/igu;
  const linkReplacement = '<a href="$<href>">$<text></a>'

  for (const line of str.split(/\r?\n/)) {
    if (line.startsWith('* ')) {
      if (context !== 'ul') {
        html += '<ul>';
        context = 'ul';
      }

      html += `<li>${line.slice(2)}</li>`;
    } else {
      if (context === 'ul') {
        html += '</ul>';
        context = null;
      }

      if (line.startsWith('= ')) {
        html += `<h1>${line.slice(2)}</h1>`;
      } else if (line.trim().length !== 0) {
        html += `<p>${line.replace(linkRegExp, linkReplacement)}</p>`;
      }
    }
  }

  if (context === 'ul') {
    html += '</ul>';
    context = null;
  }

  return html;
};
```